# Mysqldump Lock Table error while running script

Tags: debian, mysql

I have written a shell script to backup mysql all databases. The script works without any issues except this error **"mysqldump: Got error: 1017: Can't find file: 'drupal_install_test' (errno: 2) when using LOCK TABLES"**

Please help with this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Errors like this usually pop up on large databases when your filesystem has reached it's `open files limit`. Usually MySQL adopts this value from your OS, so it depends how much it is. You can check it with the query: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'open_files_limit'`, which could return something like this:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'open_files_limit';
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| open_files_limit | 1024  |
+------------------+-------+
```

Depending on the storage engine you use, a single table can use up to 2 or 3 files on your disk (like .FRM, .MYI and .MYD) so if your db has more than 512 or 341 tables, it chokes.

Now since you tagged your question with `debian`, I assume this is on a debian server. You can raise the limit with this command:

```
ulimit -n XXXX
```

Where `XXXX` is the new limit, like 2048 (don't go too extreme!). If this doesn't work or isn't saved permanently, you may need to edit the `/etc/security/limits.conf` file.

Also see [this page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/) and [this one](http://www.chrissearle.org/blog/technical/increasing_max_number_open_files_glassfish_user_debian) for references to this issue.

Comment: Hmm, just noticed this is a 2 year old question, no idea why it was on the front page. Hope this still helps other people, though.

Answer (score 0):

Do you back it up with mysqldump -A? You dont happen to have an old drupal installation script in mysql data directory?

Comment: with this option (--all-databases)

Comment: ls -l mysqls data dir please

Answer (score 0):

Try the **-f** option with mysqldump